Display images from blade assets, but do not display images from laravel browser links laravel 9
I'm looking for a way to view the images contained in a private folder in storage: here is the asset storage/app/private/images/nomefile.jpg my problem is that I would like to view the images only via asset blade and not view them via the full path of the URL, this is because I would like them not to be public but only viewable in the app after authentication, so via asset() there is a way. I've tried them all but I can't, here's the code:
Controller :
$request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:8000'
        ]);
  $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $request->image->store('images', 'private');

            $imageName = $request->file('image')->hashName();

            $safeImageName = htmlspecialchars($imageName, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            DB::table('aree')->where('id_area', $id)->update(['photo' => $safeImageName]


Blade :
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $item->photo) }}" alt="Shape2503" />

web.php for block url
Route::get('/storage/images/{path}', [ImageController::class, 'show'])->name('image.show');

controller for block url
public function show($path)
    {
        $path = storage_path('storage/images/'. $path);

        return abort(401);
    }

help me please

Apologize, I misunderstood your question.

Maybe this link helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110816/correct-way-to-remove-path-from-location-in-nginx-with-proxy-pass

Thank you. Don't worry, but is there a way? I am desperate

https://superuser.com/questions/435916/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-path-node

Unfortunately nothing goes wrong following this method at your link.

As i see. You want a route that render an image if the image exists and only if user is logged in.
Create a route
Route::get('/storage/images/{path}', [ImageController::class, 'show'])
          ->name('image.show')
          ->middleware('auth');

->middleware('auth') will protect your route in order refuse guests users to access it
Create the controller

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class ImageController extends Controller
{


    public function show($path)
    {
        $filePath= storage_path('images/'. $path); // output "/var/www/my-project/storage/images/filename.jpg"
        if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($filePath)) {
            abort(404);
        }
        return response()->file($filePath);
    }
}

Display image
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $item->photo) }}" alt="Shape2503" />

Note: If you are attempting to use a protected folder like storage which is exclusively handled by laravel, you must create a symblink of that folder in the public folder:

Create a private folder storage/images/

mkdir -p storage/images/


Map its symblink as public/storage/images/

Go to config/filesystems.php and write your redirection rule in the link section.
// config/filesystems.php
return [


    'links' => [
        public_path('storage/images') => storage_path('images'),
    ],
];


Run the symblink creator of laravel

php artisan storage:link


Display image

<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $item->photo) }}" alt="Shape2503" />

YOU HAVE THE CHOISE BETWEEN CREATING A ROUTE OR CREATING A SYMBLINK

unfortunately I can still view the image with this route and this controller. It seems that the route is not taken into consideration, I can't say why. What do you think is the reason? it could be that I have the storage:link on the public folder already exists.

I couldn't do it because the route Route::get('/images/{path}', [ImageController::class, 'showImage']); and as if it didn't coincide with http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/qEIlfcWvfxYD0e1Z65uJjNcHKj5C81t1fvR5LScZ.png

I have edited the answer in order to be more clear for you. I hope i will save you continue losing you dev time. Good luck bro!
